# Object validation using formik and yup

Tags: reactjs, formik, yup

here is my object.
food:{
veg:{
name:`, price:`
},
non_veg:{
name:`, price:`
}
}
how to validate the object, as there is options for array validation only.

Answer (score 1):

You can use yup like this:

```js
let schema = yup.object().shape({
  food: yup.object().shape({
    veg:yup.object().shape({
      name:yup.string().required(),
      price:yup.number().required(),
    }),
    non_veg:yup.object().shape({
      name:yup.string().required(),
      price:yup.number().required(),
    })
  })
});
```

And you can build your dynamic object like:

```js
let dynamic = yup.object().shape({
  food: yup.object().shape({
    [dynamicString]:yup.object().shape({
      name:yup.string().required(),
      price:yup.number().required(),
    }),
    [dynamicString]:yup.object().shape({
      name:yup.string().required(),
      price:yup.number().required(),
    })
  })
});
```

Comment: thanks, what if the object inside the food is dynamic. i.e. veg, non_veg.

Comment: I have edited my answer according to your needs. Don't forget to store it in your state.

Comment: Also you can use this link https://stackoverflow.com/a/61971503/12779513 to get more information.